# handleWindowVisibilty: no activity for the token android.os.binderproxy

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code, google-signin

google sign in not working. It gives error:

> platformException sign_in_failed.

I made sure all I listed all dependencies and google-services json file but still the error persists.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Google Auth',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }

}
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();

}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = new GoogleSignIn();

    void signin() async {
    GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    GoogleSignInAuthentication gsa = await googleSignInAccount.authentication;
    AuthCredential credential = await GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
        accessToken: gsa.accessToken, idToken: gsa.idToken);
    FirebaseUser user = await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    print("signed in " + user.displayName);
  }

  void signout(){
    googleSignIn.signOut();  
    print("Signed out");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Google Auth"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.person_add),
              onPressed: ()=>signin(),
            ),
            new IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
              onPressed: ()=> signout(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

App level gradle:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()

def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.google_auth"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Project level gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

any help or suggestion is appreciated

...........................................................................

Answer (score 1):

First you need to do the following:

1-Remove all dependencies related to google services.

2- Add latest version of Google services.

3- Synchronize your project.

Hope it helps.